# Can't access the entire page using Beautiful Soup and Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to gather data using beautiful soup and selenium and have been unable to get more than the first 20 results on the table (there are over 2000 total). I saw some related questions and answers which suggested trying different parsers, so I tried lxml, html.parser and html5lib, but none worked. I also saw some answers suggesting to use selenium and webdriver but wasn't able to get the entire page using either. This is my code as of right now

```
import requests, time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import urllib.request
#import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, time
import lxml

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/uniswap-v2/')
#supposed to scroll to the bottom of the page
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

time.sleep(5)

page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(page), 'lxml')

pairs = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {"class" : "hmd6df-0 kCRNNr"})
data = [i.find_all('a')[0] for i in pairs]
```

Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a purely selenium solution - the following python script successfully scrapes all the data from the table. I am just printing like this as an example, you will want to figure out how to organize your data.

Update: in order to expand and scrape **all** the rows, I am scrolling to the bottom of the list, then clicking the "Expand More" button, which expands 100 more rows. I am iterating this enough times to get all the way through the 1850 rows of data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/uniswap-v2/')

total_height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
for x in range(20):

    for i in range(1, total_height, 130):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))
    if x == 0:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.cmc-cookie-policy-banner__close').click()

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text() = "Load More"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
first_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td.cmc-table__cell.cmc-table__cell--sticky.cmc-table__cell--sortable.cmc-table__cell--left.cmc-table__cell--sort-by__rank > div')
second_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.cwwgik-0.bCvAgC')
third_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.hmd6df-0.kCRNNr')
fourth_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.cmc-table__column-market-pair-volume-24h')
fifth_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.cmc-table__column-market-pair-volume-percent')
sixth_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td.cmc-table__cell.cmc-table__cell--sortable.cmc-table__cell--right.cmc-table__cell--sort-by__quote-usd-effective-liquidity > div')
seventh_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td.cmc-table__cell.cmc-table__cell--sortable.cmc-table__cell--right.cmc-table__cell--sort-by__fee-type > div')
eighth_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.ghkc60-0.fLaXDt')
for i in range(len(second_column)):
    print(str(first_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")) + ' ' + str(second_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")) + '  ' + str(third_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")) + '  ' + str(fourth_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")) + '  ' + str(fifth_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")) + '  ' + str(sixth_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")) + '  ' + str(seventh_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")) + '  ' + str(eighth_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")))
```

Output:

```
1 USD Coin USDC/WETH $250,651,977 20.81% 935 Percentage Recently
2 Fei Protocol FEI/WETH $157,435,972 13.07% - Percentage Recently
3 WETH WETH/USDT $153,706,066 12.76% 915 Percentage Recently
4 Dai DAI/WETH $58,995,907 4.90% 850 Percentage Recently
5 Tendies TEND/WETH $41,429,102 3.44% - Percentage 778 hours ago
6 Wrapped Bitcoin WBTC/WETH $37,838,161 3.14% 901 Percentage Recently
7 SHIBA INU SHIB/WETH $30,416,126 2.53% 612 Percentage Recently
...

1770 yplutus  yPLT/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  671 hours ago
1771 Deflect  DEFLCT/RFI  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  96 days ago
1772 Blaze DeFi  BNFI/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  781 hours ago
1773 Buy-Sell  BSE/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1774 PIRANHAS  $PIR/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1775 HLand Token  HLAND/USDT  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1776 Hub - Human Trust Protocol  HUB/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  126 days ago
1777 WETH  WETH/YVS  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1778 Reflector.Finance  RFCTR/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1779 WETH  WETH/R34P  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1780 WETH  WETH/RFR  $?  0.00%  265  Percentage  Recently
1781 Golden Ratio Per Liquidity  GRPL/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1782 xETH-G  xETH-G/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  75 days ago
1783 3XT TOKEN  3XT/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  62 days ago
1784 Diffract Finance  DFR/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1785 Bitpower  BPP/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1786 IDL Token  IDL/ELYX  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  77 days ago
1787 IDL Token  IDL/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  81 days ago
1788 Dai  DAI/BCC  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  42 days ago
1789 Stand Share  SAS/USDT  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  123 days ago
1790 Definex  Dswap/USDT  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  314 hours ago
1791 Vaultz  VAULTZ/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  781 hours ago
1792 Fission Cash  FCX/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1793 DeltaHub Community  DHC/USDT  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  821 hours ago
1794 Dai  DAI/DST  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  111 days ago
1795 AGAr  AGAr/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  311 hours ago
1796 Basis Cash  BAC/Mars  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  809 hours ago
1797 Tether  USDT/NOW  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  781 hours ago
1798 USD Coin  USDC/wCUSD  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1799 zzz.finance v2  ZZZV2/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  781 hours ago
1800 Rigel Finance  RIGEL/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1801 Bitbot Protocol  BBP/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1802 HeroSwap  HERO/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  108 days ago
1803 XUSD Stable  XUSD/LINK  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  69 days ago
1804 XUSD Stable  XUSD/DAI  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  96 days ago
1805 CURE Farm  CURE/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1806 WETH  WETH/stETH  $?  0.00%  518  Percentage  Recently
1807 Xstable.Protocol  XST/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1808 ZCore  WZCR/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  94 days ago
1811 Wrapped BIND  wBIND/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1812 USDFreeLiquidity  USDFL/USDT  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1813 USDFreeLiquidity  USDFL/DAI  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  113 hours ago
1814 USDFreeLiquidity  USDFL/USDN  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1815 WETH  WETH/MCX  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1816 Mythic Finance  MYTHIC/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  781 hours ago
1817 Polkabase  PBASE/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1818 WETH  WETH/RAC  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1819 MiraQle  MQL/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  68 days ago
1820 MiraQle  MQL/USDT  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  68 days ago
1821 Parsiq Boost  PRQBOOST/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1822 WETH  WETH/PUX  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1823 Previse  PRVS/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1824 SIMBA Storage  SIMBA/USDT  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  781 hours ago
1825 CryptoPing  PING/USDT  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1826 Wrapped Bitcoin  WBTC/INSTAR  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1827 Vow  VOW/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1828 Value Set Dollar  VSD/DAI  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  471 hours ago
1829 Value Set Dollar  VSD/USDT  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  110 hours ago
1830 Value Set Dollar  VSD/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  44 days ago
1831 WETH  WETH/DEGENS  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1832 Xriba  XRA/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  630 hours ago
1833 Tower token  TOWER/LYM  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  469 hours ago
1834 Shadetech  SHD/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1835 Wrapped Bitcoin  WBTC/DGCL  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  333 hours ago
1836 Rare Pepe  rPepe/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1837 xSigma  SIG/USDT  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  52 days ago
1838 Dollar Protocol  USDf/USDC  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  156 hours ago
1839 MYFinance  MYFI/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1840 Delta  DELTA/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1841 Kambria Yield Tuning Engine  KYTE/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1842 ClinTex CTi  CTI/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1843 BasenjiDAO  BSJ/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1844 EURxb  EURxb/USDT  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1845 Landbox  LAND/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  442 hours ago
1846 Folder Protocol  FOL/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1847 Databroker  DTX/USDT  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1848 STATERA  STA/WSTA  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1849 Delta Exchange Token  DETO/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1850 Elongate Deluxe  ELongD/WETH  $?  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
```

Comment: I believe there are 2000+ entries, can selenium only retrieve the first 400?

Comment: Oh! I've just now seen the "Load More" button at the buttom. I will try to write some code to expand the whole thing out and scrape *all* the data.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is super helpful. This is my first time web scraping and I couldn't seem to figure out how to get past the first 20 or so entries.

Comment: @ElijahFox see the latest update to my answer for a solution to expand and scrape all 1850 rows of the table.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi again, it seems to skip the first 65 after reaching every multiple of 100 (i.e., 699, 700, 765, 766 and 799, 800, 865, 866. By any chance would you know how to fix this?

Comment: You're right I didn't notice that. Let me see if I can figure out why...

Comment: Not 100% sure but it might have something to do with the """ for i in range(1, total_height, 130):""" Half of 130 is 65 so there might be some connection.

Comment: that argument is telling the scrolling action to go 130px each time, so I wouldn't that's related. The way I define and iterate through the elements is kind of sloppy, and it will take some debugging, but when I have time I hope I can fix that.

Comment: I would message you but I am a new user and am unable to. Do you have any other suggestions? If you point me in the right direction I can try to figure it out as well.

Comment: I will take a look when I have time, right now I'm not sure why this is happening. I'm working right now but should have time later.